# SimpleXml and php: how to add an enclosure into an RSS?

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I read the XML file and loop throught the links to get link to pdf linked.

Then I want to add this link as value for the element tag of RSS. This rag must be added

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file($cached_rss);
foreach ($XML->channel->item as $index => $item) 
{ 
    // I read the page linked, grab a link to a pdf 
    // Then tried to add the new TAG to current item
    $XML->channel->item[$index]->addChild("enclosure", $link);
}
```

Actually this causes php crash without errors (any errors even in apache error.log files!)

What must I do to add a new tag as child of an existen 'item' tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already getting the `$item` in your `foreach` - that's where you want to `addChild`: `$item->addChild("enclosure", $link);`

I'm not sure why you didn't get errors tho. Try to make sure your `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`